# /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 5: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm new to Linux so I'm not sure what information you would need to help me but here is the error I get. What caused the issue was when I tried to install a deb file called tuxcut

```
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 5: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
```

Result:

```
grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $ cat /etc/environment

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games" 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle 
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre 
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java 

grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $ –
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include the command you've executed?

Comment: Lets see the contents of your `/etc/environment` file something in there is  off

Comment: @George I am very new to linux so please do explain to me how I can show you the contents of /etc/environment. Thanks a lot

Comment: Open a terminal and type `cat /etc/environment` then press enter. Copy this and post into your answer. It appears to be a minor syntax error.

Comment: grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $

Answer (score 8):

Looking at your `/etc/environment` file this line:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

aught to be:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"
```

You are missing a `"` at the end please include that and you should be fine.

To edit use `nano` text editor:

1. Open terminal with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Type: `sudo nano /etc/environment`
3. Do the edit, add the missing `"`
4. Save file with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>
5. Close `nano` with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
6. Source the file with: `source /etc/environment`

Comment: Okay, seems like that would work. Could you tell me how to edit it, please? I'm a serious noob when it comes to the terminal side. Thanks

Comment: Just to mention, this solved an issue at run react-native run-android command.