# i am trying to install apache2 on ubuntu but i`m getting an error

Tags: apt, software-installation, apache2, dpkg, software-recommendation

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libfwupdplugin1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2 libxmlb1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.2-0
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.2-0
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,821 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,949 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quote
d string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `cat /etc/environment` and `cat /usr/sbin/update-info-dir`

Comment: `/etc/environment` is sourced inside `/usr/sbin/update-info-dir` and the error message most likely means there is quoting inconsistency in one of the two files resulting in a syntax parsing error.

Comment: Most likely the quoting inconsistency(*starting quote with no matching ending quote*), *although possible to be from an earlier line*, is at the end of the `/usr/sbin/update-info-dir` file towards the end of the file in the line with `install-info`

Comment: Or around paths in `/etc/environment` ... Like [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/920048)